# Box2D library - Why the collision doesn't work properly when a dynamic body is stuck between a static body and another dynamic body?

Tags: java, c++, libgdx, box2d

For example a dynamic body is in a corner and is infinitely walking towards a wall (needs to be a static body) in that corner. If another body is walking towards the same direction, and is colliding with the first body, the collision will be completely ignored. It's the only situation where this happens.

Under here the photo:
[image]

By the next worldstep, the green rectangle overlaps the red ball. If there wasn't a static body, the collision works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would be nice if you share some code. Because now it's quite hard to help you somehow.

Comment: I add a photo of the situation^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is specific of Box2D. If One dynamic body is moving towards another dynamic body perpendicularly and there's a static body on their path, dynamic bodies will overlap each other anyway.
To fix this bug, you can use contact listener to catch the moment when bodies collide and directly set the position of the green body according to the position of the red body. Something like that:

```
public class CoreClass extends Game {


Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
World world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f), true);

Body bodyRed;
Body bodyGreen;
private float prevX;
private float prevY;

@Override
public void create() {
    BodyDef bodyBD = new BodyDef();
    bodyBD.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

    FixtureDef bodyFD = new FixtureDef();
    bodyFD.density = 1.0f;
    bodyFD.friction = 1.0f;
    bodyFD.restitution = 1.0f;

    bodyRed = world.createBody(bodyBD);
    bodyGreen = world.createBody(bodyBD);

    bodyRed.createFixture(bodyFD);
    bodyGreen.createFixture(bodyFD);

    prevX = bodyGreen.getPosition().x; prevY = bodyGreen.getPosition().y;

    world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            world.getBodies(bodies);
            bodies.get(contact.getChildIndexA()).getPosition().set(prevX, prevY);
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {

        }

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

        }

    });
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
    prevX = bodyGreen.getPosition().x;
    prevY = bodyGreen.getPosition().y;
    world.step(1/45f, 2, 6);
}
```